# How do I kill Orphan process that keeps restarting?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, process

Hey guys I need to know as I have started a python flask server manage.py in the background and then closed the terminal , now it os owned by init() and whenever i try to kill it with `kill -9 ppid`, it keeps respawning with different ppid. it is running on ubutnut-18.04.

[image]

here is the manage.py code:

```
import unittest

from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

from app import create_app, db
from app.users.models import User

app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


@manager.command
def run():
    if app.config['DEBUG']:
        app.run(debug=True)
    else:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)


@manager.command
def test():
    """Runs the unit tests."""
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests', pattern='test*.py')
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
    if result.wasSuccessful():
        return 0
    return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
------
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-101:~/CapacityPlanner/flaskapp$ ps -eaf | grep -i flask
ubuntu    1959     1  0 06:02 ?        00:00:02 /home/ubuntu/CapacityPlanner/flaskapp/venv/bin/python manage.py run
ubuntu    3451  3423  0 08:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i flask
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-101:~/CapacityPlanner/flaskapp$ kill -9 1959
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-101:~/CapacityPlanner/flaskapp$ ps -eaf | grep -i flask
ubuntu    3465     1 36 08:31 ?        00:00:01 /home/ubuntu/CapacityPlanner/flaskapp/venv/bin/python manage.py run
ubuntu    3484  3423  0 08:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i flask
```

Comment: Paste the text of ps rather than an image. Also show the logic of your start script. At the very worst, reboot the server.

Comment: added as requested